# Proof that this infinite intersection of open sets is closed

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Why is $\bigcup_{i\in N} (-1-\frac{1}{i}, 1+\frac{1}{i})=[-1,1]?$ I am not wholly convinced that  $(-1-\frac{1}{i})$ ever reaches $-1$. Doesn't it converge to it? Surely I can take n to be large but what value for n would it ever hit $-1$? Wouldn't it be $-1.00000000....1$ at best? If that's the case then why is it closed?

Comment: What number is $-1.000000\dots 1$, exactly? How many zeroes did you write?

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant to write an intersection symbol instead of the union symbol.

Regarding the confusion, the point is this. For any finite $n$, it's still an open interval. But *in the limit*, the intersection contains nothing more than $[-1,1]$.

Go ahead and try to find another number that would be in the infinite intersection. There will be some $n$ such that for all numbers larger than $n$, that number you picked is not in the infinite intersection.

Comment: +1 : Nicely stated.

Answer (score -1):

Clearly $x$:$-1<x<1$ is in the intersection. Check if any number outside is within the intersection. (Hint: It’s not. It will contradict the fact that some set within the sequence will have tighter bounds than to include that number outside $[-1,1]$).